# Storing and then "quickly" Reading Large Strings to a file with Java

Tags: java, xml

Yes I know this question is going to be technically "open ended" and might "elicit debate" but please keep in mind I am not asking for directions down the rabbit hole here, i merely want to make sure i am in the right field. SO, with that being said, here is my question:

I want to create a program that will allow the user to enter and store 1-4 sentence strings along with several other small data elements. Ideally the strings would be saved with some sort of formatting but that's another bridge. I am looking for an option that will allow me to store between 500 - 2000 of these in a single file and read back through them "fast". By "fast" i mean ideally i would like to parse back through the file and pull this one particular data element out with enough speed to "suggest" to the user while they are typing to promote consistency in language.

Now the first thing that comes to mind as a storage option is XML. So my question is:

a) am i overlooking other "relatively" equivalent storage options, and

b) understanding that there are many many MANY other variables, will using an XML file even get me in the ballpark of being able to read and display that many strings in <2 sec time frame. (assuming good coding practices and the proper XML parser type)

So is summary, pipe dream? or yes-it-can-be-done-in-certain-circumstances-with-correct-code?

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, if you want to implement "real-time" actions like this, you should try and avoid File I/O. If the data is limited to '< 2000' such Strings, then read all the Strings into a static map (`HashMap` or `TreeMap`). If you want something even faster, a suffix tree will probably be even faster, but I am note sure about that. Also, you will have to write your own code for suffix trees.

Comment: Hmm, that's what i have been thinking based on my other research, i will probably have to maintain two sets of data, on for storage and one for the suggestions.  Thanks for the HashMap and Suffix Tree pointers though.  That's the kind of information i was hoping for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't exactly answer if your idea will be executable in the ballpark of <2 seconds, it might very well be. What I can say is that it's not scalable to store the pure text in a simple **file** and read it on command like that. Even another simple approach (probably on ease of creating it as well) such as storing it in a database table with proper indexing, can probably yield a lot quicker results.

For instance, if you want to get the entire sentence if you type the first word in you can simply index the first word (in another column) and do queries through that indexed column.

Comment: yeah i thought about that, i guess i was hoping for a "single file" setup to make sharing with team members easier in the import/export/update sense but yeah the fact that you are still reading some text file worried me.

Comment: Chthonic Project's idea is also good (and quicker than this except for initialization) if you have no scalability needs or memory constraints. XML+HashMap load on start, why not?

Comment: Yup i think that's enough for me go on for now. It's worth a shot anyway. Thanks everyone!